# Unable to synchronize posix pthreads using pthread_barrier_wait()

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads, posix

I am trying to synchronize threads using pthread_barrier_wait(), but threads are not getting synchronized if the number of iterations in MAIN for LOOP is more than one. Here (s<2) is written so for 2 iterations I have mentioned the output below which is not synchronized.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

#define ARRAYSIZE 6
#define NUMTHREADS 3

using namespace std;

// Barrier variable
pthread_barrier_t barr;

unsigned int count = NUMTHREADS;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct ThreadData {
    int start, stop, tid;
};

void* squarer(void* td) {
    struct ThreadData* data=(struct ThreadData*) td;
    int start=data->start;
    int stop=data->stop;
    int tid = data ->tid;
    int i,s;

    //MAIN LOOP
    for (s=0; s<2; s++){
        for (i=start; i<stop; i++) {
            printf("thread no. %d is writing: \n", tid);
        }
    // Synchronization point
    int rc = pthread_barrier_wait(&barr);
    if(rc != 0 && rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD){
        printf("Could not wait on barrier\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (i=start; i<stop; i++) {
        printf("thread no. %d is executing: \n", tid);
    }   
}
return NULL;
}


int main(void) {
pthread_t thread[NUMTHREADS];
struct ThreadData data[NUMTHREADS];
// Barrier initialization
if(pthread_barrier_init(&barr, NULL, NUMTHREADS)){
        printf("Could not create a barrier\n");
        return -1;  
}
int i; 
int tasksPerThread=(ARRAYSIZE+NUMTHREADS-1)/NUMTHREADS;

/* Divide work for threads, prepare parameters */
for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
    data[i].start=i*tasksPerThread;
    data[i].stop=(i+1)*tasksPerThread;

data[i].tid = i;
}
/* the last thread must not go past the end of the array */
data[NUMTHREADS-1].stop=ARRAYSIZE;

/* Launch Threads */
for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, squarer, &data[i]);
}

/* Wait for Threads to Finish */
for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
}

return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

thread no. 2 is writing:
thread no. 2 is writing:
thread no. 0 is writing:
thread no. 0 is writing:
thread no. 1 is writing:
thread no. 1 is writing:
thread no. 1 is executing:
thread no. 1 is executing:
thread no. 1 is writing:
thread no. 1 is writing:
thread no. 0 is executing:
thread no. 0 is executing:
thread no. 0 is writing:
thread no. 0 is writing:
thread no. 2 is executing:
thread no. 2 is executing:
thread no. 2 is writing:
thread no. 2 is writing:
thread no. 2 is executing:
thread no. 2 is executing:
thread no. 0 is executing:
thread no. 0 is executing:
thread no. 1 is executing:
thread no. 1 is executing:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That output is synchronised fine given the code you have written.  No thread starts the 'executing' step until all threads have finished the 'writing' step.

If, in addition, you want no thread to start the next 'writing' step until all threads have finished the previous 'executing' step, you need an additional call to `pthread_barrier_wait()` after the 'executing' step.